# HP array device fails after pci slot change

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

i changed my HP 410 smart array controller from one pci slot to another because it was faulty. After the change the logical unit i had fails showing one disk as unassigned and a new one into the array

```
Smart Array P410 in Slot 5                (sn: PACCRID11231CTT)
```

array A (SATA, Unused Space: 0 MB)

```
  logicaldrive 1 (931.5 GB, RAID 1, Interim Recovery Mode)

  physicaldrive 0:1 (box 0:bay 1, SATA, 0 MB, Failed)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 1 TB, OK)
```

unassigned

```
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA, 1 TB, OK)
```

Is there any way to change the failed physicaldrive for the unassigned? the physicaldrive 0:1 doesn't exist.

System is a Windows Server 2008

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you move the controller to a different PCI slot?  What was faulty, the controller or the slot?  What model of server?  Is it in warranty?

Comment: The pci slot was faulty and it's not in warranty. Sever is  HP ProLiant ML330 G6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a RAID 1 (Mirror), your healthy disk `physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 1 TB, OK)` should be holding a complete copy of your data.  I would remove this disk and ensure the data is backed up.  Then delete the logical drive on the controller, reinstall 2 healthy disks, create a fresh array and copy the data back onto it.

I think this is the safest way, particularly if your controller is now giving incorrect information about the physical disks that are present, although this could indicate further hardware problems (disk bay backplane, controller).

Probably also worth taking the opportunity to update all firmware.

Answer (score 2):

- How did you know the PCI slot was faulty?
- What makes you think anything else on the server is okay when there's a problem on the motherboard?
- RAID metadata lives on the HP Smart Array disks, not the controller.
- It sounds like you actually need repair on your system.

You can still call HP for support on out-of-warranty items.

Answer (score 0):

The array controller was in a pci-e x16 (even the card was shorter) and the server showed blue screens several times a day, when i changed it to a pci-e x4 server is running without errors.